# definition of $T_0$-space in Dshalalow’s book

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

From the book “Real analysis: An introduction to the theory of real functions and integration” by Jewgeni H. Dshalalow (CRC Press, 2001, ISBN 1584880732, Chapter “10. Separation”, p. 182):

> **10.1 Definitions.** Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space.
>
> (i) $(X, \tau)$ is called a *$T_0$ space* if for each pair of points
>   $x\not=y\in X$, there is a neighborhood of $x$, $U_x$ such that $y\in U^c_x$

(For a subset $A$, $A^c$ denotes the complement of $A$ (Ibid., p. 6).) Am I understanding it right that this definition is equivalent to axiom  $T_1$ and therefore is incorrect?

Comment: I think you are correct. In a $T_0$ it should be: there is an open set $U$ such that $x \in U$ and $y \notin U$ **or** there is an open set $U$ such that $x \notin U$ and $y \in U$ (possibly both). From that definition, there seems to exist both, by symmetry of the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. I recall the following definitions and explanations from [Eng].

[image]

[image]
[image]

References

[Eng]  Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.